# Laravel method chaining a query through a function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, method-chaining

Is it possible to conditionally chain methods in PHP / Laravel, or to pass method chains through functions?

I'd like to control a query in Laravel's query builder by setting up a base query first, then passing that to a function to have other methods chained on to the query. As a quick example:

```
$query = Model::whereFoo('bar');

if ($needFoo) {
    $query = $query->has('foo');
}

$query = queryMethod($query);

function queryMethod($query) {
    return $query->where('something', '<', 10);
}

$items = $query->get();
```

This seems to ignore everything between `$query = Model::whereFoo('bar');` and `$items = $query->get();` -- it doesn't seem to make any difference what happens to `$query` in between the two.

Is it possible / advisable to achieve this?

**Edit:** I've accepted the answer below as it answers the question I asked. My problem was actually unrelated. If it helps anyone: I had a rogue `orWhere()` call in the base query that was of course including unwanted results regardless of the other chained methods. That needed nesting inside an advanced where method [as described in Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres).

Comment: It should be possible to just return $query; just act on the Object, in your example above your returning the result of the where() method which might work because it should be $this, but in any case you can pass the $query object around all you want, that's sort of the point of a query builder.  You should also be able to clone it and make changes on a separated copy, so for like a total with the same where logic, where you would change the select to do a count and remove limits etc...

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix - `$query` is an object that's passed by reference, so there shouldn't even be a need to return from that function. The code above should work. And that whole `$query = $query` is also superfluous.

Comment: I think I've got it. This wasn't a problem with method chaining or passing the $query object around. I think the problem was the sequence of methods. I had a `with()` call in the base query, which seems to have prevented later `where()` methods from taking effect. Does that sound right?

Comment: @Joseph Silber, good point I should have seen that I do that same thing with Doctrine's query builder... lol

Comment: @glasstree - Nope. `with` should not interfere with `where` clauses.

Comment: So am I right in thinking that any sequence of methods is fine so long as it doesn't have `get()`, `paginate()` etc. until the end?

Comment: @glasstree - Yes. Sure. As long as you're still working with the query object, you should be able to tack on whatever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have should work, but you can simplify it:

```
$query = Model::whereFoo('bar');

if ($needFoo) $query->has('foo');

queryMethod($query);

function queryMethod($query) {
    $query->where('something', '<', 10);
}

$items = $query->get();
```

Since objects in PHP are passed by reference, you'll always be dealing with the same instance.